# How to remove null matching document rows in case of populate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hello all I am new to mongodb and nodejs application .i want to join two documents and filter the same by  query but it return null when no matching is found in second document i do not want null i want to remove that complete row

Comment: can you please update with your question with your query ?

Comment: You can find this link very helpful
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

Comment: @AsadMarfani thanks for your solution with $ifNull I am able to remove the null rows sorry for the late reply